# gcc/g++ warning if comparing two pointers' addresses instead of contents?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

Suppose I have a function with pointer inputs

```
void f(int *a, int *b) {
    if (*a < *b) {
        printf("hello!\n");
    }
}
```

where `*a < *b` is the correct behavior.

Is there a warning in gcc that I can turn on so whenever I write code such as

```
a < b
```

when `a`, `b` are `int *` the compiler would warn me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There cannot be such warnings, because **`a < b`** where both `a` and `b` are pointers to `int` **is a legitimate test** that your code could do elsewhere.

<sup>A typical use case might be to represent a set of pointers by a sorted vector of pointers searched by dichotomy.</sup>

You might consider customizing GCC with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) by e.g. adding a `#pragma` to enable such a warning (in some selected places) but you'll need some time to implement the warning itself. I'm not sure it is worth spending a week of your time to customize GCC this way.

Technically, the C standard wants `a` and `b` to point inside the *same* aggregate (otherwise it is undefined behavior, or at least unspecified one), but on most systems you can compare any pointers of the same type.